# What happens if a object to which a smart pointer is pointing to commits suicide?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

I have objects that define their own "right of existence". Hence they have the possibility to commit suicide. What happens to a smart pointer that holds it? Will it be dangling or does the pointer recognises that the object destroyed itself and thus point to NULL automatically?

From outside the object I would use `ptr.reset()`. But what can I do from inside the object?

Comment: Please clarify what "suicide" does. Are you calling `delete this;`?

Comment: Couldn't that design be avoided by just composing its heavy resources and deleting those instead?

Comment: Well, I could avoid it. However it would actually be a very nice solution which would make my (physical simulation) very flexible and easy expandable. Yes, I call delete this.

Comment: When you think "the pointer recognises that the object destroyed itself and thus point to NULL automatically" you should immediately also think `weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 7):

Terrible, terrible things will happen. The smart pointer will have no idea what just happened and blindly attempt to destroy the object right on cue. This basically means that you have messed up. Objects owning themselves is highly questionable usually, but if you do own yourself, then you must never be owned externally. This directly includes smart pointers.

Proper ownership semantics means that you must have one, and only one, unambiguous owner. This is even true in the case of e.g. shared_ptr, where the object is effectively owned by the reference count.

A self-owning object must be clear about the fact that it owns itself and it is not to be owned externally.

Comment: @dani Like demons flying out of your nose.

Comment: Double deletions, double destructions, undefined behaviour in general, just things your program will not survive.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do want you want...

The object must keep itself alive using a `shared_ptr` to itself.  If that is the only `shared_ptr`, then the object can suicide by decrementing the `shared_ptr` (Probably not a good idea to call `reset()` having the `shared_ptr` destroy itself.  A better approach is to move the member `shared_ptr` into a temporary, so the `shared_ptr` member getting destroyed is not the same `shared_ptr` as the one causing destruction)

Then, from outside the objects you can use `std::weak_ptr`, and these will know when the object is destroyed.  (Because there is really a metadata object that survives and contains the state, and the `weak_ptr` checks this before accessing the object.)

It probably makes sense to inherit `enable_shared_from_this` for such an object, and then make your constructors private and friend `make_shared`.  That way it's impossible for an object instance to exist that is not managed using the internal shared_ptr.

Comment: I'd probably just have a boost slot that's called on destruction.

Comment: @Puppy: I thought "slots" were a Qt thing?  It's true that you can build your own metadata block and have everyone use a `shared_ptr<Object*>`, then the object can set that to NULL during destruction.  But this is what `weak_ptr` already does, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Friending `make_shared` isn't sufficient; for all we know it could be delegating to an internal helper.

Comment: @T.C.: but the very fact that friendship would break prevents the implementation from doing so under the As - if rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think you can go that far, or you would be essentially banning all helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an intrusive pointer. See: [Boost intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html).
Your object would need an internal reference count. In your implementation of the member function `intrusive_ptr_release` you could skip clean-up if your object has already 'comitted suicide'.